# Standard for ER diagram export format?

Tags: xml, export, data-modeling, entity-relationship

I'd like to design data models via ER diagrams, so I can discuss this more easily with customers who benefit from the visual presentation. 
In the end, I need to somehow export the resulting ER diagram to a structured format (e.g. XML), and process it further.

So far it seems that there is no standard format for this kind of diagrams. I mean there are several tools out there (like visual paradigm, StarUML, etc.) and they all offer an export to XML feature, but they all have their own XML schema. This makes my approach a little difficult, as I will be depending on the tool that I've created the ER diagram with in the first place.

If I used UML, then there would be a format standard as far as I know, but IMHO UML does not offer the flexibility of ER diagrams when designing data models.

So - back to my question: Is there any standard export format for ER diagrams, or is there any other diagram type that has a standard and might prove useful when designing data models?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Toad Data Modeler](https://www.quest.com/products/toad-data-modeler/) can export ER diagrams to SQL (DDL) with database schema

Comment: Thanks, I think for now this is the way that I'll stick to. Generate DDL and process this. Saves a detour in a way...